# Vagrant: There was an error executing the following command with VBoxManage

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

After added new shared folder like that:

```
config.vm.share_folder 'Tomcat logs', '/path_on_VM/logs/', 'logs/'
```

`vagrant up` throw error:

```
There was an error executing the following command with VBoxManage:

["sharedfolder", "add", "99d6e47f-d372-4d6e-a27b-8191deff32c8", "--name",
"Tomcat logs", "--hostpath", "/Users/w/DEV/vagrant-dev/logs"]
```

This is all what I got. I'm using `VAGRANT_LOG=DEGUG`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `/path_on_VM/logs/` it has to be owned by `vagrant` user. Wish better error messages from Vagrant.